# nw.js how to escape fullscreen

Tags: nw.js

I'm using nw.js to make an exe file. I can set it to fullscreen mode but how can I escape it using the escape key? People are suggesting the below code but which file do I put this in?

```
var gui = window.requireNode('nw.gui');
gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new gui.Shortcut({
  key: "Esc",
  active: function () {
    gui.Window.get().leaveFullscreen();
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially the following way is suggested in the documentation:
http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/FAQ/

You have to register a global hotkey:

```
nw.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new nw.Shortcut({
  key: "Escape",
  active: function () {
    // decide whether to leave fullscreen mode
    // then ...
    nw.Window.get().leaveFullscreen();
  }
}));
```

You can put this snippet at the beginning of Your app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
nw.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new nw.Shortcut({
  key: "Escape",
  active: function () {
    // decide whether to leave fullscreen mode
    // then ...
    nw.Window.get().leaveFullscreen();
  }
}));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to exit firescreen

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  var gui = require('nw.gui');
  gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new nw.Shortcut({
  key: "Escape",
  active: function () {
    // decide whether to leave fullscreen mode
    // then ...
    nw.Window.get().leaveFullscreen();
    }
    }));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this to toggle firescreen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
 var gui = require('nw.gui'); 
 gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new gui.Shortcut({
 key: "F11",
 active: function () {
    // decide whether to leave fullscreen mode
    // then ...
    gui.Window.get().toggleFullscreen();
 }
 }));
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to exit fullscreen

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  var gui = require('nw.gui');
  gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new nw.Shortcut({
  key: "Escape",
  active: function () {
    // decide whether to leave fullscreen mode
    // then ...
    gui.Window.get().leaveFullscreen();
    }
    }));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this to toggle fullscreen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
 var gui = require('nw.gui'); 
 gui.App.registerGlobalHotKey(new gui.Shortcut({
 key: "F11",
 active: function () {
    // decide whether to leave fullscreen mode
    // then ...
    gui.Window.get().toggleFullscreen();
 }
 }));
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```